# How to see that exacly is missed on device when Android Market filters out apps?

Tags: android, google-play

I have Archos tablet which cannot access my app from the Market because it filters it out from the search. The app uses-feature are very unstrict, SDK version should be OK, so I have no ideas what else is missing.
Is there a way to get Market (or 3rd party app/site) to say what hardware/software features are present on device and what are required by Market filters for my app?

my requirements are

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true"></uses-feature>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```

Furthermore, Market says that Archos 101 internet tablet matches, but 70 not (which is basically the same but smaller)

Comment: Just tried to install the app manually in the device. It says installation failed without any clear reason Ж-(

Comment: Found a workaround- exact explanation that's wrong is shown in logcat. But you need a apk and device for that

Answer (score 1):

Did you use any telephony features? phone calls/sms? My guess is that the tablet doesn't support such features that causes it to be filtered. to "bypass" that you can try adding this in the permissions

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

android:required is set to true implicitly to say that the app cannot function without this permission which should most probably be the reason why the app isn't shown.